# Do examples exist of a HOA covenants for water in a watershed?

Tags: united-states, shareholders, water

I'm looking for any precedent examples that give shape to how HOA-like covenants (group ownership) work for a natural resource — specifically a watershed.

Here are some concepts typical to HOA resources:

- monitoring
- reparations
- budgeting
- individual allotment
- review standards
- procured management

Many of them would be different for a less-tangible asset. An example of less-tangible HOA matters would be filming a movie on the HOA grounds.

Thank you for any working examples in relationship to a watershed. Better of the constituent properties are not adjacent.

Comment: In what jurisdiction? Water law is largely state law.

Comment: I think you also may be assuming that the HOA's water rights and the tenants rights as to usage between each other are interwined -- that's probably not the case (except by usage quotas set by percentage of the HOA's allocation of water under its rights or something similar). The HOA's water rights will be goverened by water law like any other entity, and the CCRs on water usage will look much like those of any other HOA with individually metered water (as seems to be implied in your question).

Comment: I am looking for examples of how an HOA's allocation is defined within the context of the county / jurisdictional law.  Probably this is a more-simple question that you're thinking.  I'm not restricting it to any one state, in hopes of gaining a few great examples.

Comment: The language "how an HOA's allocation is defined within the context of the county / jurisdictional law" is a kind of tautology. The simple answer is 'like anyone else's.' Again, from your bullet points you seem to be asking about rights between the residents, and not the HOA's water rights.

Comment: Ah, sorry , my last comment made it more confusing (it's my follow-on question).  I *am* interesting in how rights between members can work, and examples of this.  I am thinking of HOAs where the community bounds includes one or more of an entire watershed (crest to stream)

Comment: You might find the [Shady Hollow](http://www.shha.org/history.html) HOA's ["Creek Maintenance Summary Report"](http://www.shha.org/CreekCommittee/Summary%20Report_SleepyHollowHOA_June%202013.pdf) interesting.